How to extract ranges which overlap with another range from PostgreSQL multirange?
I'd like to extract ranges which overlaps with another range from multirange using SQL.
For example, {[5,10), [14,20), [26,28), [29,31)} with {[15,27)} should result {[14,20), [26,28)}.
I can achieve this with unnest and range_agg:
select range_agg(t.v) from (select unnest(:ranges) v) t where t.v && :range;

But its performance seems poor. Do you have any idea doing it in more efficient way?
PS. I wish there was & operator like this:
{[5,10), [14,20), [26,28), [29,31)} & {[15,27)} -> {[14,20), [26,28)}


"performance is poor" Performance of what exactly? I assume you apply this to a table. So show the table definition, existing indexes, cardinalities, your query, the resulting query plan, and always your version of Postgres. The usual stuff for performance questions. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Your operation is not commutative. You wrote {[15,27)} (type e.g. int8multirange), not [15,27) (type int8range), i.e. same type as the first operand yet giving it a different role: {[5,10), [14,20), [26,28), [29,31)} & {[15,27)} -> {[14,20), [26,28)} but I suppose {[15,27)} & {[5,10), [14,20), [26,28), [29,31)} -> {[15,27)}. That fact alone makes is unlikely to have a Postgres-defined operator. Are you sure that is what you want?

There is the intersection operator * for multiranges:
SELECT int4multirange '{[5,10), [14,20), [26,28), [29,31)}' * int4multirange '{[15,27)}';

But that only returns actual overlaps, while you want every single overlapping range in toto. For that, your query is already as good as it gets.
Depending on the actual query in use there may be additional tweaks to increase performance - like filtering overlapping ranges with index-support first.
